# download a series of files automatically using command line/wget

Tags: windows, command-line, download, wget

I have a case that I would like to trigger an automatic download for a list of 114 file (recitation) for each reader,
for example if i want to download the recitations for a reader called `abkr`, the urls for the files will look like the following..

`http://server6.mp3quran.net/abkr/001.mp3`
`http://server6.mp3quran.net/abkr/002.mp3`
`...`
`http://server6.mp3quran.net/abkr/113.mp3`
`http://server6.mp3quran.net/abkr/114.mp3`

simply these are Quran recitations, so they are always have a total of 114

is there an easy way to loop that using `command line` on **Windows** ?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Windows is preferred, Mac is Ok as well..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here's a batch-only solution:

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /L %%G IN (1, 1, 114) DO (
    SET num=%%G
    IF 1!num! LSS 100 SET num=0!num!
    IF 1!num! LSS 200 SET num=0!num!
    wget http://server6.mp3quran.net/abkr/!num!.mp3
)
EndLocal
```

**Edit 1:** Removed unnecessary braces.

**Edit 2:** Corrected counter start value to 1.

Comment: all solutions are great, but I'm gonna accept this since it is straight forward (command-prompt), and does not require something other than wget..

Comment: a small correction, the loop starts from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Oops, correcting...

Answer (score 6):

You haven't stated OS, but if you are using *nix and Bash the following works:

```
wget http://server6.mp3quran.net/abkr/{001..114}.mp3
```

---

A solution that should work with any shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(seq -w 1 114); do
    printf 'http://server6.mp3quran.net/abkr/%s.mp3 ' $i
done | xargs wget
```

or, if `seq` does not exist on the system:

```
#!/bin/sh
i=1
MAX=114
while [ $i -le $MAX ]; do
    printf 'http://server6.mp3quran.net/abkr/%03d.mp3 ' $i
    i=$((i+1))
done | xargs wget
```

Just copy+paste it in the shell or save it in a script file and run it.

Comment: is Mac OSX included in your `*nix` solution ?

Comment: anasnakawa: Yes, you can run Bash on MacOSX, but it is not the default shell, I believe. Try just running the command "`bash`" in a terminal. You might need to install it beforehand, or look for a simple solution using the default shell. To clarify: the above will definitely work, but it might not be the most obvious way if Bash is not already installed.

Answer (score 4):

For a Windows solution, try the following PowerShell script:

```
$Client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
for ($i = 1; $i -le 144; $i++)
{
    $file = [string]::Format("{0:D3}.mp3", $i)
    $Client.DownloadFile("http://server6.mp3quran.net/abkr/" + $file, $file)
}
```

First `cd` into the directory you want to download the files to, of course.

Answer (score 0):

For reference and the sake of completeness a version without seq, a nice output and continue if the download stops for whatever reason:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in 00{1..9} 0{10..99} {100..144}; do
    printf 'http://server6.mp3quran.net/abkr/%03d.mp3 ' $i
done | xargs wget -q --show-progress -c
```